# places on ecommerce website where we can inject brand personality

Tags: copywriting, visual-design, branding

what are some screens on an commerce website where we can inject brand personality, using visuals and copy

e.g. https://www.pinterest.com/angstrm/fun-404-page/ is a typical example

some other places i could come up with

- empty cart and wishlist
- pre loader messaging

what other screens would provide a great opportunity for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it's in line with your brands personality, the right micro copy could delight your user or even alleviate some anxiety.

Here are some situations I could come up with.

- No results after search
- After purchasing
- Email confirmations

A good resource for quirky and fun micro copy is Tiny Words Matter. They're Tumblr blog is not updated regularly anymore I think, but they're active on Twitter.
https://tinywordsmatter.tumblr.com/
https://twitter.com/tinywordsmatter

I do want to warn you about [confirm-shaming](http://confirmshaming.tumblr.com/). You could go overboard with trying to be funny in your micro copy and even offend your visitors.